# update Process Configuration in Azure DevOps server 2020

Tags: xml, azure, process, azure-devops-server-2020, azure-devops-services

I am update my TFS 2018 update 3 to Azure devops Server latest version. Now i want to migrate to Azure devops service. I am use azure devops migration tool, and when i started this tool i have error "Validation Proccess faild". I read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-processtemplates?view=azure-devops
And i am fixed a lot of error in my process file, but now i have error in a last step:
Step 6: Conform project - Process Configuration
The following element contains an error: PortfolioBacklog(Microsoft.EpicCategory). TF400522: The following value is not a valid work item category: Microsoft.EpicCategory. You must specify a valid category.
The following element contains an error: PortfolioBacklog(Microsoft.FeatureCategory). TF400522: The following value is not a valid work item category: Microsoft.FeatureCategory. You must specify a valid category.
The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog. TF400522: The following value is not a valid work item category: Microsoft.RequirementCategory. You must specify a valid category.
The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog. TF400522: The following value is not a valid work item category: Microsoft.TaskCategory. You must specify a valid category.

This is my process configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProjectProcessConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <WorkItemColors>
        <WorkItemColor primary="FF009CCC" secondary="FFD6ECF2" name="ProductBacklogItem" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FF773B93" secondary="FFEEE2F2" name="Feature" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF7B00" secondary="FFFFD7B5" name="Epic" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFF2CB1D" secondary="FFF6F5D2" name="Task" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFCC293D" secondary="FFFAEAE5" name="Bug" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Code Review Request" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Code Review Response" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Feedback Request" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Feedback Response" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Impediment" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Shared Step" />
        <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Test Case" />
     <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Test Plan" />
     <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Test Suite" />
     <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Shared Parameter" />
  </WorkItemColors>
  <TypeFields>
    <TypeField refname="System.AreaPath" type="Team" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="RemainingWork" format="{0} h" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" type="Order" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" type="Effort" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity" type="Activity" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationStartInformation" type="ApplicationStartInformation" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationLaunchInstructions" type="ApplicationLaunchInstructions" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationType" type="ApplicationType">
      <TypeFieldValues>
        <TypeFieldValue value="Web application" type="WebApp" />
        <TypeFieldValue value="Remote machine" type="RemoteMachine" />
        <TypeFieldValue value="Client application" type="ClientApp" />
      </TypeFieldValues>
    </TypeField>
  </TypeFields>
  <PortfolioBacklogs>
    <PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.EpicCategory" pluralName="Epics" singularName="Epic" workItemCountLimit="1000">
      <States>
        <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
        <State value="Active" type="InProgress" />
        <State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" />
        <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />
      </States>
      <Columns>
        <Column refname="System.WorkItemType" width="100" />
        <Column refname="System.Title" width="400" />
        <Column refname="System.State" width="100" />
        <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" width="50" />
        <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" width="50" />
        <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" width="100" />
        <Column refname="System.Tags" width="200" />
      </Columns>
      <AddPanel>
        <Fields>
          <Field refname="System.Title" />
        </Fields>
      </AddPanel>
    </PortfolioBacklog>
    <PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Features" singularName="Feature" parent="Microsoft.EpicCategory" workItemCountLimit="1000">
      <States>
        <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
        <State value="Active" type="InProgress" />
        <State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" />
        <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />
      </States>
      <Columns>
        <Column refname="System.WorkItemType" width="100" />
        <Column refname="System.Title" width="400" />
        <Column refname="System.State" width="100" />
        <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" width="50" />
        <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" width="50" />
        <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" width="100" />
        <Column refname="System.Tags" width="200" />
      </Columns>
      <AddPanel>
        <Fields>
          <Field refname="System.Title" />
        </Fields>
      </AddPanel>
    </PortfolioBacklog>
  </PortfolioBacklogs>
  <RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Stories" singularName="User Story" workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <States>
      <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
      <State value="Active" type="InProgress" />
      <State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" />
      <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />
    </States>
    <Columns>
      <Column refname="System.WorkItemType" width="100" />
      <Column refname="System.Title" width="400" />
      <Column refname="System.State" width="100" />
      <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" width="50" />
      <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" width="100" />
      <Column refname="System.IterationPath" width="200" />
      <Column refname="System.Tags" width="200" />
    </Columns>
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
  </RequirementBacklog>
  <TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task" workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <States>
      <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
      <State value="Active" type="InProgress" />
      <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />
    </States>
    <Columns>
      <Column refname="System.Title" width="400" />
      <Column refname="System.State" width="100" />
      <Column refname="System.AssignedTo" width="100" />
      <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" width="50" />
    </Columns>
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
  </TaskBacklog>
  <Weekends />
  <Properties>
    <Property name="BugsBehavior" value="Off" />
  </Properties>
</ProjectProcessConfiguration>
```

Any ideas how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error means that you do not have the specified values in the Categories.xml file. You need to add these values to the file and try the import again. I would also like to recommend you another approach: if you are migrating, you do not have to fix the file with the configuration process, since all work items are also stored in your database. You can use witaminadmin.exe to import an empty configuration file into your azure devops server, then again, using witaminadmin.exe, delete all templates such as Bug, Spike, Issue, and so on one by one. And then run Azure DevOps Migration Tools again and the migration should start, unless of course you have other errors. When the project is migrated, you can use Azure Boards Queries to restore all your work items. That's all :) Choose for yourself which approach you like best.